# Understanding Full Join in Django

Tags: sql, django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models in my app:

```
# Create your models here.
class Melody(models.Model):
    notes = models.JSONField()
    bpm = models.IntegerField()
    aimodel = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    score = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    person = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, related_name="melodies")
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Vote(models.Model):

    user_score = models.IntegerField(validators=[MaxValueValidator(1), MinValueValidator(-1)])
    melody = models.ForeignKey(Melody, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="scores")
    person = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="voters")

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.person} - {self.melody} - {self.score}"
```

And I get the melodies of the current user by

```
# Get melodies of current user
melodies = Melody.objects.all().filter(person=person).order_by('-score')[start:end+1].values()
```

I would like to add to this results the vote of the user to each melody, if there is one, otherwise just null so I can loop over the melodies and retrieve the values:

```
melody.notes = ...
melody.bpm = ...
melody.user_score = This is the values I do not know still how to get, Null if user has not voted
```

I was reading about select_related but when I use it it always says
*"Invalid field name(s) given in select_related: 'xxxx'. Choices are: (none)"*

What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I solved it based on the answer of @Fnechz by making two queries and then looping over the elements so I can add the user_score to the melody:

```
# Get melodies of current user
melodies = Melody.objects.all().filter(person=person).order_by('-score')[start:end+1].values()

# Get votes of the user
votes = Vote.objects.all().filter(person=person)

for i, m_melody in enumerate(melodies):
    for m_vote in votes:
        if (m_vote.melody.id == m_melody['id']):
            melodies[i]['user_score'] = m_vote.user_score
            
return  JsonResponse({"melodies": list(melodies)})
```

Not sure if this is the best way to achieved it

Comment: Usually you would access ` user_score` by querying the Vote class. Can you clarify how exactly you queried for the ` user_score`field

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would like to get a "table" with a single query (if possible) that has all the columns of the Melody Class filter by the user, plus another column of "user_score" if this user has any register in the Vote Class (has voted for the melody)

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if there is a direct method to accomplish what you want with a single query. But I guess concatenating the queryset results might work.

```
from itertools import chain
melodies = Melody.objects.all().filter(person=person).order_by('-score')[start:end+1].values()
votes = #query your vote model here to get the user_score
result_list = list(chain(melodies,votes))
```

If I have understood your question that might work

Comment: Hi @Fnechz, thank you very much for your answer, so I solved it by querying melodies and the votes as you suggested but then I loop over the elements. I would like to still have the question open to see if there is a better way to do it, creating a kind of Full Join query... I will add in the question an EDIT showing how I solve it so it is more clear my question

Comment: Sure, but Django doesn't support full joins(inner or outer) in the usuall SQL sense, you could try mimicking it by defining a tuple with None's where there are missing combinations. Anyway try looking at this link you might get some insights: https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2009/09/28/custom-joins-with-djangos-queryjoin/